# HTML/Jquery How to limit number of child divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 pages. Each page has a parent div of the same class. User can horizontally scroll from one page to another. Also, user can add child divs dynamically into the parent container.
The user will start adding divs from parent (in page 1).

I have two questions:

1. Using jquery how can I limit the number of child divs to 3. If the user tries to add another it is added to page 2 (unless page 2 has 3 child divs, then it would go to page 3)?
2. Once the parent container of page 3 is full (3 divs) an alert should pop up saying "You cannot add anymore divs!!".

Please help me. I am novice in all this stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Related image:
[image]

Sample code::

```
 <script>
$("addbutton").click(function(){
$("#child").appendTo(".parent");
});
</script>


//page 1
<div class= "parent">
<div id= "child1">
</div>
<div id= "child2">
</div>
<div id= "child3">
</div>
</div>

//page 2
<div class= "parent">

</div>

//page 3
<div class= "parent">

</div>
```

Comment: Added sample code. Thanks for showing interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I came up with:

```
var $pages = $('.page');
var child = '<div class="child"></div>';

$('button').on('click', function () {

  var childAdded = false;

  $pages.each(function () {
    var $page = $(this);
    if ($page.children().length < 3) {
      $page.append(child);
      childAdded = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!childAdded) {
    alert('You can not add anymore divs!');
  }

});
```

I loop through each `.page` and check the number of children. If there's less than 3 children I add one then escape from the loop by returning false.

With a small demo: http://jsbin.com/nuyipuya/3/edit

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/w6AAq/

```
if($(".parent").children().length < 4) {
     console.log('Less then or equal to 3')   
}else {
     console.log('Cannot add any more child elements')   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("addbutton").click(function(){
    if($(".parent").children().length<3)
{
    $("#child").appendTo(".parent");
}
else
{
      alert("You can not add any more divs");
}
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/